# How do I perform comparative mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query will return the location ETL's and which table was pulled and when in the ETL process.  I want to create a query which shows me any locations which have a max(date_pulled) for the settings table > max(date_pulled) for the events table.

```
SELECT

location_id, table_name, max(date_pulled)

FROM
ods.etl_log
where table_name in ('events','settings')

group by location_id, table_name
```

The result looks like this:

```
location_id | table_name | max(date_pulled)
20          | events     | 2014-12-04
20          | settings   | 2014-12-05
26          | events     | 2014-12-04
26          | settings   | 2014-12-03
```

But my final result I would like to look like this:

```
location_id | max(date_pulled) settings | max(date_pulled) events | settings > events?
20          | 2014-12-05                | 2014-12-04              | Yes
26          | 2014-12-03                | 2014-12-04              | No
```

Do I need to use nested joins to do this?  One for the events, and the other for settings, then join them together and create an if field?

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of `pivoting`.  You can achieve these results in mysql a couple ways, here's one with `max` and `case` putting your results in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    location_id, 
    max(case when table_name ='events' then maxdate_pulled end) maxdateevent,
    max(case when table_name ='settings' then maxdate_pulled end) maxdatesettings,
    max(case when table_name ='settings' then maxdate_pulled end) > 
           max(case when table_name ='events' then maxdate_pulled end) settingsgreater
FROM (
    SELECT location_id, table_name, max(date_pulled) maxdate_pulled
    FROM ods.etl_log
    WHERE table_name in ('events','settings')
    GROUP BY location_id, table_name
) T
group by location_id
```

Comment: why is the max before the case?

Comment: This worked!  thanks so much!  Also, instead of making it show 0 or 1 in the settingsgreater column, how do I make it show "Yes" or "No"?